# Ordered Cursor ListView

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have a simple question about using SimpleCursorAdapter with ListView. I've noticed that my cursor retains it's internal structure, but that the ListView connected with a SimpleCursorAdapter seems to display the objects in the cursor in a odd, or even random, order.

It's important that my list view display the Cursor's objects in the same order that they appear in the Cursor. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: It appears that issue is not with ListView or Cursor. The issue is that a Cursor returned by using a WHERE IN (x,y,z) clause will not necessarily have the order x, y, z. Sorry for posting the misleading query.

Comment: I'm surprised by this. Are you specifying an order-by in the db query?

Comment: No, I'm finding a subset of objects by using a WHERE IN with a list of _id's. _id's may be random or repeated. Like WHERE _id IN (5,4,5,8,2). However the creation of this Cursor ends up, that order is important. The order as in from c.moveFirst() to last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple cursor adapter shows items in listview in reverse order... Not random... Check it out

Comment: Wow... can't believe I missed that pattern! Is there any way I can change that behavior? Do I have to override some behavior or is there  a simpler solution?

Comment: I believe items are in reverse order of ur cursor, i.e cursor.movetoend to movetofirst.